# Why does my JDBC keep setting session variables?

Tags: mysql-5.7, jdbc, aws-aurora

I'm looking at the Performance Insights for MySQL Aurora on AWS and among the top queries I see:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

These statements don't appear in my code anywhere, I couldn't find them in the HikariCP implementation, in the MySQL/J driver or the JDBC connection string. I was able to confirm that the last query `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` occurs when a new connection is created. These queries are wasteful since they come from a reader instance. Any ideas on how to trace and stop this?

This is with HikariCP 3.4.5, mysql connector 8.0.11 and MySQL 5.7. Below is a screenshot of what Performance Insights shows. Note that setting session parameters is 4 of the top 5 queries by Average Active Sessions. The wait event in green is `wait/io/aurora_respond_to_client`, so I guess it's just waiting for the client to confirm receipt.
[image]

Comment: They are wasteful in what sense?

Comment: They take up the database's time. If I understand correctly this setting is entirely unnecessary in a reader instance.

Comment: How much time do you think it takes to set a session variable?

Comment: If you'd asked me without data I'd say no time at all. But Performance Insights says it takes up a lot. I've added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: I guess we have different views on what "a lot" means. Looks like it adds whopping 0.002% to the query latency. Personally, I'd find myself a bigger fish to fry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you couldn't find it in the driver code, it's [certainly there](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/dd61577595edad45c398af508cf91ad26fc4144f/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java#L2200):

```java
    public void setTransactionIsolation(int level) throws SQLException {
      ...    
            if (shouldSendSet) {
                switch (level) {
                    ...
                    case java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED:
                        sql = "SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED";
                    ...
                }

                this.session.execSQL(null, sql, -1, null, false, this.nullStatementResultSetFactory, null, false);
                ...
```

You can reduce frequency of these calls by setting the `alwaysSendSetIsolation` property to `false`.